# Classless Python module initialization with a data-dependency

Tags: python

I'm currently tasked with improving a kludged Flask application (`App.py`) by splitting things up into different files. The old application had some global state to hold a database connection object and numerous top-level functions to perform database operations, like so:

```
dbc = SomeDatabaseConnection( CONNECTION_STRING )

def get_users():
    result = dbc.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    # do stuff
    return processed_result
```

So far I've moved all of the database logic to another file (`Database.py`), retaining the classless design, but there's a problem: I don't know how to initialise the `dbc` object:

In the old single-file application, we had a hardcoded `CONNECTION_STRING` global, however as we want to reuse `Database.py` in other projects we don't want to hard-code the string in that file - and in fact we now load it from a YAML file, so I need to find a way to pass the string from the YAML file, via `App.py` and into `Database.py`.

How?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to add a function to database.py.  The function takes the connection string as an argument and sets the global dbc variable.  Programs that use the database.py module will need to call the new function before they can use any of the other database functions.  Something like:

```
# database.py

dbc = None

def open_database(connection_string):
    global dbc
    dbc = SomeDatabaseConnection(connection_string)

# program.py

open_database( CONNECTION_STRING )
```

Comment: Yes, I'm going with this approach - I'd have thought that having a "module-init" function might be a bad Python "code smell" but if it's sound then I'll go with it, thanks.

Comment: Ideally, you would change the module to use classes.  Then your programs would instantiate an instance of the database class, passing the connection string as a init argument.  All the module functions could be methods.  But your question implied you wanted to keep the class-less design.  Maybe the redesign is phase 2.

Comment: @RootTeo I understand a core tenet of modern Python philosophy is to avoid classes that exist only to hold state and group functions together - that they must only exist when they would result in less code than a normal module. Currently converting the DB code to a class wouldn't result in that.

Comment: Using a class lets you have multiple db connections (to the same or different dbs) if needed.  Using a global variable to hold the connection will not let you do that.  If you look at the source code for the one of the data persistence modules, e.g., dbm or shelve, you will see they have an `open` function that returns a class which implements the interface.